# How to add random numbers between two sets of text vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, numbers

Okay so I have been trying to make a junk code generator for C++ (new to vb.net just trying to get somewhat familiar with different languages) and I am stuck at being able to call random numbers between two lines of text
currently I am stuck at

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button4.Click
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((10000 * Rnd()) + 9999999))
Me.RichTextBox1.Text = (
" float pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" if (pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
"If(pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" If (pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" If (pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" If (pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" If (pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";" +
" pJunkcode = " + value + ";")`
```

The error I am getting is

> Conversion from string "pJunkcode" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is hard to notice when you come from C-languages. In VB
the `+` operator has different behaviours depending on the types of the expresions involved. In this case, one is a string and the other is a number, so the `+` operator is trying to first parse the `String` to a `Double`, to finally add the 2 numbers. You've got all this information here: [+ Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addition-operator)

> One expression is a numeric data type and the other is a string:
>
> If Option Strict is On, then generate a compiler error.
>
> If Option Strict is Off, then implicitly convert the String to Double and add.
>
> If the String cannot be converted to Double, then throw an InvalidCastException exception.

In your case, you can solve the problem by using the string concatenation operator [& Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator):

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
 Button4.Click
   Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((10000 * Rnd()) + 9999999))
    Me.RichTextBox1.Text = (
    " float pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " if (pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    "If(pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " If (pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " If (pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " If (pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " If (pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";" &
    " pJunkcode = " & value & ";")
```